# Creating Text Fields programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using Xcode 4.6.1. I want to know how can I create various text fields on the same view controller, separated by some space between them, with the text set programmatically.

Comment: Just you would do with any other object: `UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];`

Comment: @H2CO3 But how can I put the text field visible on an especific position of the view controller screen?

Comment: Just like you would do with any other view: `tf.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Havent test this code but your question is fairly simple, quick google would give you the results.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //first one
    UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 30, 200, 40)];
    tf.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/256.0 green:84/256.0 blue:129/256.0 alpha:1.0];
    tf.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:25];
    tf.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    tf.text=@"Hello World";

    //second one
    UITextField *tf1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, tf.frame.origin.y+75, 200, 40)];
    tf1.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/256.0 green:84/256.0 blue:129/256.0 alpha:1.0];
    tf1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:25];
    tf1.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    tf1.text=@"second field";

    //and so on adjust your view size according to your needs
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 400, 400)];
    [view addSubview:tf];
    [view addSubview:tf1];

    [self.view addSubview:view];

}
```